# Python - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and just starting to learn. Please help me with the below code.

```
def sum_divisors(n):
  sum = 0
  divisor = 1
  while divisor < n
  if n % divisor = 0
      sum = sum + divisor
    divisor += 1

  # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n

  return sum

print(sum_divisors(0))
# 0
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1
# 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18
# 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51
# 114
```

However, I am getting the below error, please help:

```
Error on line 4:
    while divisor < n
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `if n % divisor = 0` should be `if n % divisor == 0`  - same for your other line. Single `=` is assignment, double `==` is equality check and you need to add a `:`

Comment: What did you already try to solve this problem? It's a Syntax Error, meaning you've got the syntax wrong. Did you read anything about Python? Did you check the [documentation of the while statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the trailing ":": `while divisor < n:`.

There are also various problems with the indentation.

This may fix your code:

```py
def sum_divisors(n):
    sum = 0
    divisor = 1
    while divisor < n:
        if n % divisor == 0:
            sum = sum + divisor
        divisor += 1

    # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```py
def sum_divisors(n):
  sum = 0
  divisor = 1
  while divisor < n:
      if n % divisor == 0:
          sum = sum + divisor
      divisor += 1
```

It's simple syntax: there's supposed to be a ":" after the `while` and `if` statements.
And indentation after that.
Also == for if statements

Answer (score 0):

You need a colon (`:`) after the `while` and `if` statements and proper indentation, and the `=` is for variable assigning, the operator for equality is `==`:

```
def sum_divisors(n):
  sum = 0
  divisor = 1
  while divisor < n:
    if n % divisor == 0:
      sum = sum + divisor
    divisor += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `:` after `while`,`if`,`for` and function definitions. Also you need to check the equality with `==` instead of `=`.

```
def sum_divisors(n):
  sum = 0
  divisor = 1
  while divisor < n:
    if n % divisor == 0:
       sum = sum + divisor
    divisor += 1

  # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n

  return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

There were few mistakes of missing colon. I have fixed them.

```
def sum_divisors(n):
    sum = 0
    divisor = 1
    while divisor < n: 
        if n % divisor == 0:
            sum = sum + divisor
        divisor += 1

  # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n

    return sum

print(sum_divisors(0))
# 0
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1
# 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18
# 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51
# 114
```